# defining webapp load order in jetty

Tags: jetty

I have two webapps that might be deployed separately or in the same jetty server.  In my situation, one webapp must deploy before the other can complete its deployment, so I'm looking for a solution in the dual deployment case where I can define the deployment order.

I've defined a context xml file with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
  <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList">
      <Set name="handlers">
        <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
          <Item>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
             <Set name="contextPath">/security</Set>
             <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/security_app/war/</Set>
             <Call name="addAliasCheck">
               <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ApprovePathPrefixAliases"/>
               </Arg>
             </Call>
           </New>
         </Item>
         <Item>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
             <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
             <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/main_app/war/</Set>
             <Call name="addAliasCheck">
               <Arg>
                 <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ApprovePathPrefixAliases"/>
               </Arg>
             </Call>
           </New>
         </Item>
       </Array>
     </Set>
   </New>
 </Configure>
```

However, with this solution, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.createContextHandler(WebAppProvider.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App.getContextHandler(App.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
```

which of course, is true, though they both are AbstractHandlers in the end.  What might I be doing wrong or is there another way to pull this off?

Using Jetty 9.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have hardcoded deployments, don't use the `deploy` module.

The exception you are getting is the `deploy` module attempting to find and deploy webapps itself, and is failing to find the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler` entry it is expecting.

The best way to fix this is to not have separate webapps that depend on each other during deploy/init (that is out of scope for the servlet spec).  Make the `/main_app/war/` webapp init on demand, not on startup.

Now back to your specific problem ...

> **Important: do not work / edit / run / configure the `${jetty.home}` directory directly.**
>
> The `${jetty.base}` directory exists for a reason, use it, you'll be much happier when you do.
>
> http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html

For those things that are load order sensitive, do not use the `deploy` module with those artifacts. (its safe to use the `deploy` module for other webapps you have that don't have load order dependencies)

To accomplish this, we'll configure a `${jetty.base}` directory to use a custom xml file on startup, along with a `/special/` directory for these load order dependent `WebAppContexts`, making sure that these contexts are *not* loaded, and managed by the `deploy` module.

```
$ cd my-jetty-base
$ mkdir etc
$ gvim etc/special-deploy.xml
$ echo "etc/special-deploy.xml" >> start.ini
$ ls -F
etc/  special/  start.ini  webapps
$ ls -F special/ 
main.war  security.war
$ cat start.ini
--module=http
jetty.port=8080
--module=deploy
etc/special-deploy.xml
```

The `special-deploy.xml` looks like this ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Add Load Order Dependant Webapps                                -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">

  <Call name="addHandler">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
       <Set name="contextPath">/security</Set>
       <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.base"/>/special/security.war</Set>
       <Call name="addAliasCheck">
         <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ApprovePathPrefixAliases"/>
         </Arg>
       </Call>
     </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

  <Call name="addHandler">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
       <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
       <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.base"/>/special/main.war</Set>
       <Call name="addAliasCheck">
         <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ApprovePathPrefixAliases"/>
         </Arg>
       </Call>
     </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

</Configure>
```

When you run you'll see the following ...

```
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-distribution-9.2.10.v20150310/start.jar 
2015-04-29 12:18:55.929:INFO::main: Logging initialized @275ms
2015-04-29 12:18:56.093:WARN:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: ApprovePathPrefixAliases is not safe for production
2015-04-29 12:18:56.094:WARN:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: ApprovePathPrefixAliases is not safe for production
2015-04-29 12:18:56.097:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.10.v20150310
2015-04-29 12:18:56.150:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /security, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2015-04-29 12:18:56.166:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@751d30f6{/security,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-security.war-_security-any-3863723758166154575.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/examples/load-order-example/special/security.war}
2015-04-29 12:18:56.181:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2015-04-29 12:18:56.183:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4f79a28b{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-main.war-_-any-2704851460101920295.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/examples/load-order-example/special/main.war}
2015-04-29 12:18:56.184:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/joakim/examples/load-order-example/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-04-29 12:18:56.195:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@4ef6d773{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-04-29 12:18:56.196:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @542ms
^C2015-04-29 12:19:09.594:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-0: Stopped ServerConnector@4ef6d773{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-04-29 12:19:09.599:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4f79a28b{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-main.war-_-any-2704851460101920295.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/examples/load-order-example/special/main.war}
2015-04-29 12:19:09.602:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@751d30f6{/security,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-security.war-_security-any-3863723758166154575.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/examples/load-order-example/special/security.war}
```

Comment: If I don't use the deploy module, how then do I get jetty to load my context xml file?  Is there a command line option?