# How to configure web application deployment priority in jetty

Tags: deployment, configuration, jetty-9

**Web Server:** Jetty 9.4.24.v20191120

I have multiple web applications and its context xml deployed in jetty server. I would like to know if there are any jetty configurations available to set deployment priority or sequence for each web application.

Answer (score 0):

I found the configuration details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931005/11733763) which would allow us to specify the web application load/deployment order in jetty